# Use header('Location: $url') when include (or require) statement used

Tags: php, redirect, xampp

Suppose there is a file tree

```
/[PROJECT_ROOT]/include-caller-1.php
/[PROJECT_ROOT]/subfolder/yet-another-include-caller-2.php
/[PROJECT_ROOT]/subfolder/subfolder2/yet-another-include-caller-3.php
/[PROJECT_ROOT]/subfolder/page-get-included.php
/[PROJECT_ROOT]/subfolder/jump-to-this-page.php
```

The three 'include-caller.php' that include 'page-get-included.php' by proper 'include' statement.

/include-caller-1.php

```
include("/subfolder/page-get-included.php");
```

/subfolder/yet-another-include-caller-2.php

```
include("page-get-included.php");
```

/subfolder/subfolder2/yet-another-include-caller-3.php

```
include("../page-get-included.php");
```

In /subfolder/page-get-included.php, it will make a redirect to 'jump-to-this-page.php' with something like:

```
header("Location: " . realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . "/jump-to-this-page.php"));
```

but it won't work as expected.

What's more, the relative location of `[PROJECT_ROOT]` compared to `htdocs` is flexible. It might be `htdocs/project/`, `htdocs/`, etc.

In a word, neither `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` nor the location of caller.php is predictable. There is only one thing is true: 'page-get-included.php' and 'jump-to-this-page.php' are just next to each other.

In this case, how to uniformly make a redirect to 'jump-to-this-page.php' from all the possible caller files?

Comment: `__FILE__` contains the file system path, which you wouldn't send in a header location because it's not publicly accessible along that path. Use relative public paths to `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can establish the http path to your include file (not project root in this case), regardless of document root or aliases, by finding the difference between file system path and public http path in `page-get-included.php`

```
$path_real = __DIR__;
$path_real_difference = str_replace($path_real, '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
$path_web = str_replace($path_real_difference, '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```

So now you can reference this path to `jump-to-this-page.php` regardless of where it was included from.

```
header("Location: $path_web/jump-to-this-page.php");
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I make it work based on your idea. `$debug_page_dir = __DIR__;`
   `$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];`
    `$relative_dir = explode("htdocs", $debug_page_dir, 2)[1];`
    `$url = "http://" . $host . $relative_dir . $pageName;`